# Find the following limit 0/0

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

$$\lim_{t\to 0} \frac{\left(\sqrt{t+9}-3 \sqrt[3]{2 t+1}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{t+8}-2 \sqrt[3]{3 t+1}}$$

I tried to multiply the nominator by conjugation but got even bigger expression.

Comment: Hint: $(a^3-b^3)=(a-b)(a^2+ab+ b^2)$

Comment: and L'Hospital doesn't help?

Comment: @Nex, Thanks. Unfortunately, this hint didn't help me and I got really big expression in the nominator.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the tag is limits-without-lhopital

Comment: There might be a better way to solve it but use $(a^6-b^6)=(a-b)(a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5)$ for the numerator and what I suggested for the denominator.

Comment: i think the Limit doesn't exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\sqrt{t+9}$, $b=3\sqrt[3]{2t+1}$, $c=\sqrt[3]{t+8}$ and $d=2\sqrt[3]{3t+1}$.
We have 
$$ \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{a-b}{c-d} = \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{a^6 -b^6}{c^3-d^3}\right)\left( \frac{c^2+cd + d^2}{a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5}\right)
= \lim_{t\to 0}\left(\frac{(t+9)^3 -(3^6(2t+1)^2)}{t+8 - 8(3t+1)}\right)\left( \frac{c^2+cd + d^2}{a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5}\right)=\left(\frac{3(9^2) -4(3^6)}{-23}\right)\left(\frac{3(4)}{6(3^5)}\right)=\frac{22}{23}.
$$

Note that on the last line we used: $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(t+9)^3 -(3^6(2t+1)^2)}{t+8 - 8(3t+1)} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(t^3+3(9)t^2+3(9)^2t + 9^3) - (3^6(4t^2+4t+1))}{-23t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(t^3+3(9)t^2+3(9)^2t) - (3^6(4t^2+4t))}{-23t} = \lim_{t\to 0}\frac{(t^2+3(9)t^1+3(9)^2) - (3^6(4t+4))}{-23} = \frac{3(9^2) -4(3^6)}{-23}$$
and $\lim_{t\to 0} a = \lim_{t\to 0} b=3$ and $\lim_{t\to 0} c = \lim_{t\to 0} d=2$.

Answer (score 1):

Use $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(1+x)^a-1}{x}=a$ and $\frac1{a^{1/3}-b^{1/3}}=\frac{a^{2/3}+a^{1/3}b^{1/3}+b^{2/3}}{a-b}$

Then the limit equals to 
\begin{align}
& \lim_{t\to 0}3[(1+t/9)^{1/2}-(1+2t)^{1/3}] \times \frac{(t+8)^{2/3}+(t+8)^{1/3}(24t+8)^{1/3}+(24t+8)^{2/3}}{(t+8)-(24t+8)} \\
= & -\frac{36}{23}\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{[(1+t/9)^{1/2}-1]-[(1+2t)^{1/3}-1]}{t} \\
= & -\frac{36}{23}\left(\lim_{t\to 0}\frac1{9}\frac{[(1+t/9)^{1/2}-1]}{t/9}-\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{2[(1+2t)^{1/3}-1]}{2t}\right) \\
= & -\frac{36}{23}(\frac{1}{18}-\frac{2}{3}) \\
= & \frac{22}{23}.
\end{align}

Comment: There is an error on the second last line $*$ should be $-$. It should be $$=-\frac{36}{23}\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{9}\frac{[(1+t/9)^{1/2}-1]}{t/9}-\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2[(1+2t)^{1/3}-1]}{2t}\right)$$

Comment: @Nex Thank you, my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest (and systematic) way is to use *Taylor's formula* at order $1$:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\left(\sqrt{t+9}-3 \sqrt[3]{2 t+1}\right)}{\sqrt[3]{t+8}-2 \sqrt[3]{3 t+1}}&=\frac{3\biggl(\sqrt{1+\dfrac t9}-\sqrt[3]{1+2t}\biggr)}{2\biggl(\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac t8}-\sqrt[3]{1+3t}\biggr)}=\dfrac{3\Bigl(1+\dfrac t{18}-1-\dfrac{2t}3+o(t)\Bigr)}{2\Bigl(1+\dfrac t{24}-1-t+o(t)\Bigr)}\\
&=\frac{-\dfrac{11t}6+o(t)}{-\dfrac{23t}{24}+o(t)}=\frac{22+o(1)}{23+o(1)}=\frac{22}{23}+o(1)
\end{align*}
So the limit as $t$ tends to $0$ is equal to $\color{red}{\dfrac{22}{23}}$.

Comment: Your expression $\frac{3\biggl(\sqrt{1+\dfrac t9}-\sqrt[3]{1+2t}\biggr)}{2\biggl(\sqrt{1+\dfrac t8}-\sqrt[3]{1+32t}\biggr)}$ should be $\frac{3\biggl(\sqrt{1+\dfrac t9}-\sqrt[3]{1+2t}\biggr)}{2\biggl(\sqrt[3]{1+\dfrac t8}-\sqrt[3]{1+3t}\biggr)}$ and shouldn't $o(t)$ be $o(t^2)$?

Comment: @Nex 2 Thanks for pointing the typo in the denominator. As to th other point, no it is $o(t)$ (negligible w.r.t. $t$) – I think you're confusing with Bachmann's notation $O(t^2)$ (dominated by $t^2).

Comment: @Axoren: I just skipped one trivial detail, using the rules of calculation for asymptotic analysis, just writing the $o(1)$ outside the fraction. I've added the missing step, but frankly, I don't think it was necessary.

Comment: @Bernard I see where my mistake was. My introduction to little-o was from time complexity analysis where $f(x)$ such that $f(x) = o(g(x))$ was simply presented as $f(x) \le \varepsilon g(x)$. In general asymptotic analysis, we're not given the luxury of only dealing with non-negative functions. With the correct definition of little-o, $|f(x)| \le \varepsilon |g(x)|$, you're correct, your missing step is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

By using the first two terms in the generalized binomial development,
$$\frac{\sqrt{t+9}-3 \sqrt[3]{2 t+1}}{\sqrt[3]{t+8}-2 (3 t+1)}=
\frac{3\left(\frac t9+1\right)^{1/2}-3 (2 t+1)^{1/3}}{2\left(\frac t8+1\right)^{1/3}-2 (3 t+1)^{1/3}}\approx
\frac32\frac{\frac t{18}-\frac{2t}3}{\frac t{24}-t},$$

which tends to $\dfrac{22}{23}$.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the limit in the seemingly more complicated way
$$
\lim_{t\to0}
  \frac
   {\dfrac{\sqrt{t+9}-3}{t}-3\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{2t+1}-1}{t}}
   {\dfrac{\sqrt[3]{t^3+8}-2}{t}-2\dfrac{\sqrt{2t^3+1}-1}{t}}
$$
Each piece in the above expression is the ratio for computing the derivative at zero of a function. If you don't know derivatives yet, you can still rationalize each piece in a simpler way than trying to do it for the expression in the original form.